# PHP Slicing a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, slice

I have the following `print_r()` from a multi-dimensional array (for simplicity I have not included all information in the array:

**print_r()**

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
  ...
)
[41] => Array (
  [name] => London 
  [company] => nhyt6t
  [top25_1] => 8.75912088
)
[42] => Array (
  [name] => Manchester
  [company] => gtr4rf
  [top25_1] => 6.56758398
)
  ...
[75] => Array (
  [name] => Leeds
  [company] => de3wsd6
  [top25_1] => 7.58675398
)
)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to slice the array so that I get the information from array `[41]` upwards into a new array.

I know I can use `array_slice()' but my following code doesn't work and I am sure it's because the array I am slicing from is multi-dimensional and I can't work out how to achieve this.

**Non working code**

```
$array = array_slice($row, 40);
```

Any and all feedback and advice welcomed.

Comment: So you want from 41 and up?

Comment: Yes, that's correct Darren.

Comment: What does your non working code produce? That seems fine

Comment: `$array = array_slice($row, 40, (count($row) - 40));` Should work -> [**JSFiddle**](https://eval.in/169383)

Comment: @Darren *Psst - that's `eval.in` - not `jsfiddle`*

Comment: @h2ooooooo Shiat good spot! Got the fuzzies here and it's too late to edit it :-(

Comment: Cheers all - that's now working - most odd.  Not sure what was going on there!

Comment: Darren - if you pop yours down as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Homer_J Posted answer :)

Comment: As a matter of interest, can anyone explain why this question has a downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check the manual on php -> [`array_slice()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$array = array_slice($row, 40, (count($row) - 40))
```

You simply forget to supply the 3rd parameter (`$length`) which we do as a count from the 41 *nth* item to up :)

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/169383)

Comment: 3rd parameter is not necessary. from manual: "If it is omitted, then the sequence will have everything from offset up until the end of the array."

Comment: @FuzzyTree - you are correct, however, for reasons that I don't know - this worked whereas my code didn't.

Comment: @FuzzyTree I realised that, but as you saw it didn't work for the OP so I offered an alternative :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result = array();
for($i=40;$i<count($row);$i++)
{
   if(array_key_exists ($i,$row))
   {
       $result[$i] = $row[$i];
   }

}
print_r($result );
?>
```